# Best practices for similar RBAC schemas?

Tags: reactjs, express, rbac

I all, I'm writing a boilerplate for future projects. Composition is as follows:

Server:
Express,
Prisma 2,
Typescript,
JWT Auth (Access token in memory, Refresh in cookie)
MySQL

I'm writing an RBAC schema, and have successfully written express middlewares to determine if a user is logged in, and for if a user has a specific permission on their role.

If you've ever used any of the minecraft server permission plugins, I'm trying to emulate the common pattern used there.

- Users have role(s)
- Roles have permissions
- Roles can inherit permissions from one or more roles
- Roles have a "nextRole" field to determine what role to give when the "promote" event is triggered.

Everything works fine on the server side.

What I'm wondering about is, how should I go about copying the middlewares (login, permissions) to the client side, and how should I determine whether a user has permission to do something?

What I've looked at:

- Creating a "hasPermission" endpoint wouldn't be very good as I'd need to make an API call every time a permission check is needed.
- Eager loading all roles and permissions from the api when logging in and returning them in the response (I can't eager load the recursive role inheritance/nextRole as far as I know)
- Returning ONLY the user without roles and permissions for the JWT/login bit and getting roles/permissions from their own endpoints (again, needs to be recursive to get all inheritance and said permissions from inheritance)

Has anyone created an RBAC schema like this, and how did you go about checking permissions on the client side without being too redundant/using too much memory/too many api calls?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, here's my answer to it.

An app is normally protected by the auth info, which means it could be blocked if a user is not permitted. If this is a server application, it can be easily done, because the session can be used to find out the current user info including roles.

However if this is a client app, it's a bit tricky. Say we can protect a route (page or section of page) once the user log in.

```
  if (!user.authenticated) return null
```

We can use the above line to block private or public user. Or other information you can grab from the user to protect more.

```
 if (user.role !== 'Admin') return null
```

We could wrap in these into a component, such as

```
  <Allow role="admin" render={...} />
```

I believe you get the point. However there's something which is very unique about the client approach. The entire user info is returned back, and only the user info, not the user type or permission type.

So to follow your plan, do we need to share a permission or role type to the client side? This is a million dollar question.

In practice, the UI never needs the complete info, why? because UI normally reshapes the permission a bit. That doesn't mean you can't share the complete info from the backend. Doing that may make the UI job easy or more complicated. Nobody knows.

The reason is what I explained above, the UI is writing a `if` statement (could be hidden) anyway. Either this `if` is true or false, most of the front-end code is already loaded. It's very different than the backend version, which can entirely block the deliver of the content.

Comment: The idea I'm looking for is like `user.can("permission.node"), and it'll check the user's role and role inheritance for that permission. Server side, this is easy. Client side though, I'm thinking about where I should pull that information from, how often i pull said information to the client to make sure it's "in sync" with the server's rbac state.

Comment: For example, Let's say I want to render a component ONLY when the user has permission. How should I go about local storage of the permission nodes the user has? Should I get a full list of permissions from the role and its inheritance, cache that on the client side, and use that for permission checks, or should I just make the hasPermission API call every time I need to check, or should the user object be fully structured with the fully recursive role structures for the checks?

Comment: Actually i can't answer that question, i think you need to experiment on both. My guts feeling, making a `hasPermission` API is too expensive. Because overall it's about a `if`, so you just need some definition of user type which can be duplicated over from the backend.